# GroupBy in a python-Pandas dataframe with score corresponding to occurence in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of my city that contains the people's evaluation of neighbourhood problems and looks something like that:

```
personID hood problems                               problemTop1 problemTop2 problemTop3 other columns
0001     A    ['cars', 'air', 'trash', 'parks', ...] 'trash'     'cars'      'air'       ...
0002     D    ['cars', 'air', 'trash', 'parks', ...] 'cars'      'air'       'trash'     ...
0003     A    ['cars', 'air', 'trash', 'parks', ...] 'cars'      'parks'     'air'       ...
0004     M    ['cars', 'air', 'trash', 'parks', ...] 'parks'     'cars'      'air'       ...
...
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ISZM_U7zqHoiF-o4OXCC-zmctDhQz9i/view?usp=sharing) is a short version of the dataframe with only the important columns. I would like to group the dataframe by neighbourhoods (`hood`) and give each of the possible problems a score. The score should be a weighted sum of how problematic the people perceived the problem and as an example should look like that - if in neighbourhood `E` 10 people perceived `trash` as `problemTop1`, 7 people as `problemTop2` and 3 as `problemTop3`, then

`E_score_trash = 10*3 + 7*2 + 3*1 = 47`

My final output should show for each neighbourhood each problem's score, like this:

```
>>> df_scores_by_hood
hood 'air' 'cars' 'parks' 'trash'
A     386   871    321     984
B     436   719    504     620
C     383   230    848     601
D     881   524    231     783
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this with pandas, numpy or other functions? Tnx

Comment: can you provide your input as DataFrame object?

Comment: @mozway Thanks, I added a link in the text to my dataframe. NaNs indicate that a person hasn't completed the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I am not happy with it - it's not really pandasic, it's not vectorized (it does loops) and I have the feeling there should be something simpler for my problem. Do you know how to improve it?

```
# list of all the problems
problems = ['cars', 'air', 'trash',...]

for problem in problems:
    df[problem] = 0
    df[problem] = df.apply(lambda row: 3 if row['problemTop1']==problem
                           else 2 if row['problemTop2']==problem
                           else 1 if row['problemTop3']==problem
                           else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Did not fully understand the question originally, thus the initailly wrong answer. This

```
problems =  {'problemTop1':10,'problemTop2':7, 'problemTop3':3}
agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
for problem in problems:
    temp = pd.crosstab(df['hood'],df[problem],colnames=['problem'])
    temp = temp*problems[problem]
    agg_df = agg_df.add(temp,fill_value=0)
agg_df.astype(int)
```

should do the task in an efficient way.

---

Original

you need to explode the list column by

```
df = df.explode('problems')
```

then you can do a crosstab or in my experience better perform a double groupby and unstack.

```
df_scores_by_hood = df.groupby(['hood','problems'])['personID'].count().unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks Arnau and welcome to StackOverflow! :) Unfortunately, `df.explode` doesn't do anything meaningful in my case, because in contains in every row exactly the same entry. It just contains all the possible choices each person can make. I came up with a solution on my own, you can have a look at it. It's not elegant, because it is not vectorized and I wonder if you have an idea for a shorter solution? Tnx